# Is there a database/collection of relations/properties in Mathematics?

Tags: reference-request, relations

Looking at [this Wikipedia page on Relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relation_(mathematics)), there is a decent amount already collected there in terms of relations (like >=) and relation "properties" (like associativity). I am really looking for more things like "associativity". There is also the "[Equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation)" wiki page, which might add some insight.

Are there any missing relations/properties not included on these two pages? I am not looking for answers of the missing relations/properties, as it would be dozens of partial answers probably and not a great fit for StackExchange. But I am looking for perhaps a book or website (like some Math wiki) which aggregates *all* possible relation/property types.

The reason for this is as follows. I am building a fantasy language and would like to know what the full breadth and depth is of mathematics (and in this case, of mathematical relations), so that I may translate it into a fantasy language. I need something that organizes and simplifies it all so I know I have covered the full spectrum and have not left anything out, but which also cuts out a lot of the duplication and "basic-ness" you find on the web when searching "list of mathematical relations" and the like. So the aggregation resource could be extremely advanced, that doesn't bother me, I am just hoping it covers wide ground.

**Basically, what are all the relation properties like "associativity" that you could possibly define? And where could I find such a list collecting all these relation properties?**

They don't necessarily need to be limited to any particular slice of mathematics (like just binary relations, or just with arithmetic operations). Ideally it would cover as many fields of mathematics as possible. If no such resource exists, would it be possible to piece it together from some smaller parts? If so, from where? If not, what is my best bet then?

Comment: Relations on what set exactly? Or any set? This sounds a bit unrealistic to me.

Comment: Yeah on any set I guess.

Comment: Well there are uncountably many relations on $\mathbb{N}$, so a list of them in definitely out of the question. Might I ask how you intend to build a fantasy language using such information? The full breadth and depth of mathematics is not known to anyone and likely never will be.

Comment: @Lance Creating an archive of important relations could be a fun project! Not one I have time for, but I'd be interested if you started one.

Comment: @Lance I may have misunderstood, so you are looking for 'important properties' of relations, like associativity and commutativity, or a list of the relations themselves, or just the 'important' relations?

Comment: Yes I would just like a big list consisting of "associativity", "commutativity", etc. as big as the list can get.

Comment: @Lance I don't know a reference for such a list, but the answer certainly depends on what additional structure the set may have. For a non-empty set $G$ with a binary operation $*$, you have associativity and commutativity, the possibility of an identity ($ea=ae=a$ for all $a$) and then the property of each element having an inverse relative to that identity ($ab=ba=e$). This of course is an abelian group. Adding a second binary operation (considering the first as addition and the second as multiplication), there are distributivity laws etc. and the properties of rings and fields.